# JAWR sorting order of nested files

Tags: java, angularjs, jawr

Started to use JAWR to bundle my AngularJS files, but ran into an issue when it tried loading the files out of order.

My directory structure:

- app

  - app.js
  - folderA

    - something.controller.js
    - something.module.js

I would like it to load the files in this order: app.js, something.module.js, something.controller.js

It's currently loading the controller first, then the module; causing a nomod error (no module exits).

The [docs](https://jawr.java.net/docs/source_ordering.html) say to use a .sorting file, but I can only get it to work if I make a .sorting file in each folder, where I really just want to make one at the root directory.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that creating a .sorting file at each level is the only way to get it working.